# SQL Count Instances of Value and Order by highest number, where value is a year

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have an SQL Table as follows

**Year**

2007
2007
2007
2007
2006
2006
2006
2006

Year is of type VARCHAR(4) and is not of type DATE. In instances where the number of Years are equal (here - 4-2006, 4-2007), I would like the later year to be the year selected.

Here is my SQL Query:-

```
SELECT `Year`, COUNT(*) FROM `results` GROUP BY `Year` LIMIT 1
```

However, it returns 2006 and not 2007. I tried using an ORDER BY and/or dropping the GROUP BY at the same time but to no effect.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `ORDER BY`.  Just to get the most recent year:

```
SELECT `Year`, COUNT(*)
FROM `results`
GROUP BY `Year`
ORDER BY `Year` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not sure I know what you mean by:  "here the number of Years are equal".  However, I speculate:

```
SELECT `Year`, COUNT(*)
FROM `results`
GROUP BY `Year`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, `Year` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Correct entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You need to use `ORDER BY` `DESC` for get height number of `year`

```
SELECT Year, COUNT(*) as height_number
FROM results
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year DESC
LIMIT 1
```